# Find rows that are not in table1 but possibly in table 2 or table 3

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add a value from `table_2` and `table_3` that is not yet been added to `table_1`.

Say `table_1` and `table_2` have some product names, I want the products to be added to `table_1` that already isn't there, (I have read-only access to `table_2` and `table_3`)

What I have done is to get rows of `table_2` and `table_3` by querying each table and do an in_array check in php with result from query of `table_1` and then add rows if not found.

Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: i did as posted in the question and it works, 
all i am trying to find out is if there is a way to make a union of table 2 and table 3 and the select from the union the rows which are not available in table 1, 
i am not very good with writing advanced queries

Comment: `    INSERT INTO `DstnTable` (`product_name`) 
    VALUES (SELECT `product_name` FROM `SourceTable`)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `product_name` = VALUES(`product_name`);`

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful to show us the code you have, and that's working?

Comment: @Creatix post your sql query

Comment: try with union concept @Creatix

Comment: $current_prod select * from `table1`
$table2 select * from `table2`
$table3 select * from `table3`

$temp_prod = array();
$to_add_prod = array();

foreach ($current_prod as $key => $value) {
 array_push($temp_prod,$value['pname']);
}

foreach ($table2 as $prods) {

 if(!in_array($prods['pname'],$temp_prod)){
  array_push($to_add_prod,$prods['pname']);
 }
}
foreach ($table3 as $prods) {

 if(!in_array($prods['pname'],$temp_prod)){
  array_push($to_add_prod,$prods['pname']);
 }
}

Comment: Capitalization, formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Solution #1

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO tbl1 (product_name) 
SELECT product_name FROM tbl2
UNION
SELECT product_name FROM tbl3
```

It is simple but not very efficient as it loads all the rows from `tbl2` and `tbl3` just to discard some of them that already exist in `tbl1`.

#### Solution #2

If most of the entries in `tbl2` or `tbl3` already exist in `tbl1` then using a `JOIN` will make the query run much faster:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (product_name)
SELECT tbl2.product_name
FROM tbl2 LEFT JOIN tbl1 USING (product_name)
WHERE tbl1.product_name IS NULL
UNION
SELECT tbl3.product_name
FROM tbl3 LEFT JOIN tbl1 USING (product_name)
WHERE tbl1.product_name IS NULL
```

This query selects from `tbl2` and `tbl3` only the `product_name`s that does not already exist in `tbl1` and inserts them there.

#### Solution #3

I think it's even better to split the last query in two separate queries on `tbl2` and `tbl3` and run them individually:

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (product_name)
SELECT tbl2.product_name
FROM tbl2 LEFT JOIN tbl1 USING (product_name)
WHERE tbl1.product_name IS NULL
```

and

```
INSERT INTO tbl1 (product_name)
SELECT tbl3.product_name
FROM tbl3 LEFT JOIN tbl1 USING (product_name)
WHERE tbl1.product_name IS NULL
```

This one works better than query #2 when `tbl2` and `tbl3` has many values of `product_name` in common.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
 INSERT INTO tbl1 (product_name) 
 SELECT product_name FROM tbl2 UNION SELECT product_name FROM tbl3
 ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE product_name = VALUES(product_name)
```

Comment: Why `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`? If `product_name` is not an `UNIQUE` index then there is no duplicate problem on `INSERT`. And if it is an `UNIQUE` index then the query updates `product_name` with its own value (it's the one that produced the duplicate conflict).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know which one is better performance-wise (on duplicate key update) or where product_name not in... but here's another alternative

```
insert into tbl1 (product_name)
select product_name from tbl2 where product_name not in (select product_name from tbl1)
union
select product_name from tbl3 where product_name not in (select product_name from tbl1)
```